# Independent webView didFinish WKNavigationDelegate methods for multiple WKWebView instances

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Is there a way to have different actions occur when different webViews are finished loading? If I have `webView1` and `webView2`, how can I create two independent `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` functions that get called individually for one of the webViews finishing loading?

Comment: just compare if delegate method is called by webView1 or webView2, like so `if (webView == self.webView1) { // do something } else if (webView == self.webView2) { // do something else }`

Comment: @AamirR That worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WKNavigationDelegate` or any protocol's methods can only be inherited available once per class, but you can easily figure out which instance the delegate method was called from, like so:

```
class YourClass: WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView1: WKWebView!
    var webView2: WKWebView!

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if (webView == self.webView1) {
            print("didFinishNavigationWebView1")
        } else if (webView == self.webView2) {
            print("didFinishNavigationWebView2")
        }
    }

}
```